# Troubles getting an actual macOS version

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm using the following code:

```
NSOperatingSystemVersion macOsVersion()
{
    return [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion];    
}
```

It's working fine when I build it on my machine - it returns `11.5.1` version.
But, we use Jenkins, which is working on a remote macOS machine, and a build from Jenkins shows `10.16.0` version on my machine.

I'm not an experienced macOS developer. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better API?

Comment: https://eclecticlight.co/2020/08/13/macos-version-numbering-isnt-so-simple/

Comment: It depends on what SDK you are linking against. Anything before macOS 11.0 SDK will result in the reported version being 10.16 on macOS 11 or newer because Apple expects a lot of people only checking the minor version in their existing apps. Update Xcode on Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CTABUYO for the code example, and [mikdusan](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/7569), the solution is to read contents of the `/System/Library/CoreServices/.SystemVersionPlatform.plist` file. It's not affected by macOS version compatibility stuff (at least for now).

```
if (FileExists("/System/Library/CoreServices/.SystemVersionPlatform.plist"))
{
    NSDictionary* systemVersion = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/.SystemVersionPlatform.plist"];
    NSString *macOSVersion = [systemVersion objectForKey:@"ProductVersion"];
    NSLog (@"productVersion =========== %@", macOSVersion);
}
else
{
    NSDictionary* systemVersion = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"];
    NSString *macOSVersion = [systemVersion objectForKey:@"ProductVersion"];
    NSLog (@"productVersion =========== %@", macOSVersion);
}
```